# Running a loop upon button press

Tags: c, loops, button, arduino

I need help looping a few statements for a line tracker whenever I press '0' on the keypad and for it to continue looping till the button is pressed again where it then goes back to running the main loop. Any help is most welcome.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <DS1307RTC.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Keypad.h>

//Pins of LCD     RS  E  D4 D5  D6 D7
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7); // Pins of Arduino
Servo servoMain; // Define our Servo
int tempPin = A0; //LM35 Pin
int ldrPin = A1;  //LDR Pin
int led = 6;    //LED Pin
int buzzer = 13;
float temp;
float tempC;
int lightReading;
int numTones = 2;
int tones[] = {440, 349};
int Tones = 3;
int ones2[] = {988, 740, 988};
int bulb = A2;
int val;
int motor1Pin1 = 26; // pin 2 on L293D IC
int motor1Pin2 = 25; // pin 7 on L293D IC
int enable1Pin = 27; // pin 1 on L293D IC
int motor2Pin1 = 23; // pin 10 on L293D IC
int motor2Pin2 = 22; // pin 15 on L293D IC
int enable2Pin = 24; // pin 9 on L293D IC
int state;
int flag = 0;      //makes sure that the serial only prints once the state
int stateStop = 0;
int s1val;
int s2val;
int led1 = 43;
int led2 = 42;
const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 3; // Three columns
// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3'},
  {'4', '5', '6'},
  {'7', '8', '9'},
  {'*', '0', '#'}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {48, 53, 52, 50};
// Connect keypad COL0, COL1 and COL2 to these Arduino pins.
byte colPins[COLS] = {49, 47, 51 };

// Create the Keypad
Keypad kpd = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup()
{
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(tempPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bulb, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor1Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor1Pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable1Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2Pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable2Pin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(enable1Pin, HIGH); // set to high so that motor can run
  digitalWrite(enable2Pin, HIGH); // set to high so that motor can run
  servoMain.attach(3); // servo on pin 3
  servoMain.write(72);
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  kpd.addEventListener(keypadEvent);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  setSyncProvider(RTC.get);   // the function to get the time from the RTC
  if (timeStatus() != timeSet)
    Serial.println("Unable to sync with the RTC");
  else
    Serial.println("RTC has set the system time");

  lcd.clear();
  beep(100);
}
void loop()
{
  tempC = (5.0 * analogRead(tempPin) * 100.0) / 1024;
  temp = tempC;
  lightReading = analogRead(ldrPin);
  val = analogRead(3);
  Serial.println(val);
  digitalClockDisplay();
  s1val = analogRead(6);
  s2val = analogRead(7);
  char key = kpd.getKey();

  if (Serial.available() > 0)
  {
    state = Serial.read();
    flag = 0;
  }

  if (val >= 700)             // check if the input is HIGH
  {
    val = analogRead(3);
    doSomething('f');
    delay(1000);
    if (val >= 700)
    {
      doSomething('g');
    }

    else
    {
      doSomething('m');
    }
  }

  else
  {
    doSomething('m');
  }

  if (temp >= 35 && temp < 50) // "Hot Warning" temp
  {
    doSomething('a');
  }

  else if (temp >= 34 && temp < 35) // "Warm Warning" temp
  {
    doSomething('b');
  }

  else if (temp >= 50) // "Danger Warning" temp
  {
doSomething('c');
  }

  else
  {
    doSomething('m');
  }

  if (lightReading > 100 && lightReading <= 200) // Dim Warning
  {
    doSomething('d');
  }

  else if (lightReading <= 100) // Dark Warning
  {
    doSomething('e');
  }

  else
  {
    doSomething('m');
  }

  if (state == '1') //Motor
  {
    doSomething('h');
  }

  else if ( state == '2')//Motor
  {
    doSomething('i');
  }

  else if ( state == '3')//Motor
  {
    doSomething('j');
  }

  else if ( state == '4') //Motor
  {
    doSomething('k');
  }

  else if ( state == '5')//Motor
  {
    doSomething('l');
  }

  else
  {
    doSomething('m');
  }

  if (key) // Check for a valid key.
  {
    switch (key)
    {
  case '1':

    Serial.println(key);
    servoMain.write(72);  // Turn Servo to 0
    break;

  case '2':

    Serial.println(key);
    servoMain.write(0);  // Turn Servo Left to 36 degrees
    break;

  case '3':

    Serial.println(key);
    servoMain.write(36);   // Turn Servo Left to 72 degrees
    break;

  case '4':

    Serial.println(key);
    servoMain.write(108);  // Turn Servo left to 108 degrees
    break;

  case '5':

    Serial.println(key);
    servoMain.write(144); // Turn Servo left to 144 degrees
    break;

  case '6':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;

  case '7':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;

  case '8':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;

  case '9':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;

  case '0':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;

  case '*':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;

  case '#':

    Serial.println(key);
    break;
    }
  }

  delay(300);
  lcd.clear();
  Serial.print("Light,"); Serial.print(lightReading); Serial.print(" "); Serial.print('\n');
}

void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent key) {
  switch (kpd.getState()) {

    //U can use three modes: PRESSED, HOLD or RELEASED.
    //U can also add more than one event with more than one key.
    case PRESSED:
      if (key == '0') {
        if (s1val <= 0 && s2val >= 2) //turn left
        {
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
        }

        else if (s1val >= 2  && s2val <= 0) // turn right
        {
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
        }

        else if (s1val >= 2 && s2val >= 2) // go forward
        {
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
        }

        else // stop
        {
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
          digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
        }
      }
  }
}

void doSomething(char condition) {
  switch (condition) {
  case 'a' :  // if temp is higher than 35°C
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   Room Hot!!   ");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(150);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  break;

case 'b' :  // if temp is higher than 30°C
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("   Room Warm!   ");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(150);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  break;

case 'c' :  // if temp is higher than 50°C
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("    Warning     ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("    Danger!!    ");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep2(150);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  break;

case 'd' : // if room is dim
  analogWrite(bulb, 150);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("   Room Dim!!   ");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(150);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  break;

case 'e': // if room is dark
  analogWrite(bulb, 255);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("   Room Dark    ");
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(150);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
  break;

case 'f': //  when motion detected by I.R Sensor
  analogWrite(bulb, 0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Motion Detected");
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  break;

case 'g':                  //motion detected turn on light for 20secs
  analogWrite(bulb, 255);
  delay(5000);
  break;

case 'h':                        // forward
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, HIGH);
  break;

case 'i':                        //left
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
  break;

case 'j':                        //stop
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
  break;

case 'k':                        //right
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, HIGH);
  break;

case 'l':                        //reverse
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
  break;

default:
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Time:");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0);                                            // Set LCD cursor position (column, row)
  lcd.print(hour());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print (minute());
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print(second());
  lcd.print("     ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Date:");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1);                                           // Set LCD cursor position (column,row)
  lcd.print(day());
  lcd.print(".");
  lcd.print(month());
  lcd.print(".");
  lcd.print(year());
  analogWrite(bulb, 0);
  break;

  }
}

void beep(unsigned char delayms) { // buzzeer tones for room hot and warm
  for (int x = 0; x < numTones; x++)
  {
    tone(buzzer, tones[x]);
    delay(delayms);
  }
  noTone(buzzer);
}
void beep2(unsigned char delayms2) { // buzzer tone for room above 50°C
  for (int y = 0; y < Tones; y++)
  {
   tone(buzzer, ones2[y]);
    delay(delayms2);
  }
  noTone(buzzer);
}

void digitalClockDisplay() {
  // digital clock display of the time
  Serial.print(hour());
  printDigits(minute());
  printDigits(second());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(day());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(month());
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(year());
  Serial.println();

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Time:");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0);        // Set LCD cursor position (column, row)
  lcd.print(hour());
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print (minute());
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print(second());
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Date:");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1);       // Set LCD cursor position (column,row)
  lcd.print(day());
  lcd.print(".");
  lcd.print(month());
  lcd.print(".");
  lcd.print(year());

  // Print text to LCD
  // Delay to read text
  // Clear the display

}

void printDigits(int digits) {
  // utility function for digital clock display: prints preceding colon and leading 0
  Serial.print(":");
  if (digits < 10)
  Serial.print('0');
  Serial.print(digits);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to keep doing something after a button has been pressed you need a "toggle" variable that is set once the button is pressed and reset when the button is pressed again.

In your global declarations you can put `bool mustDoIt = false;` and in your `main()`:

```
if (keyPressed) {
  mustDoIt = !mustDoIt;
}

if (mustDoIt) {
  ...
}
```

Quite a few things that I notice:

- You have a big `if ... else` for `temp` (which by the way is not a good name, it could mean either `temperature` or `temporary`), on which you call another function, inside of which you make the same check. Why not passing the temperature to the function and checking it inside of it?
- You repeat code a few times,

Consider writing a function for this:

Something like:

```
void displayMessage(char *first_row, char *second_row) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(first_row);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(second_row);
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  beep(150);
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  delay(200);
}
```

- You basically only check on `temp`, `state` and `lightReading`, so as I said, move the checks where you actually need them. Pass those three variables to `doSomething` and do the checks in there.

Something like this:

```
void doSomething(float temp, int state, int lightReading) {
  if (temp >= 35 && temp < 50)
  {
    displayMessage("   Room Hot!!   ", "");
  } else if (temp >= 34 && temp < 35)
  {
    displayMessage("   Room Warm!   ", "");
  } else if (temp >= 50)
  {
    displayMessage("    Warning     ", "    Danger!!    ");
  } //...Add rest of the checks here

  switch (state) {
    case 1: //Motor
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, HIGH);
    break;
    case 2:
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(motor1Pin2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(motor2Pin2, LOW);
    break;
  //...Add rest of the checks here
  }
```

And the same goes for `lightReading`.

Also, the `digitalClockDisplay` function can be written as:

```
void digitalClockDisplay() {
  char time_string[32];
  char date_string[32];

  memset(time_string, 0, 32);
  sprintf(time_string, "Time: %02d:%02d:%02d     ", hour(), minute(), second());
  memset(date_string, 0, 32);
  sprintf(date_string, "date: %02d.%02d.%02d     ", day(), month(), year());

  displayMessage(time_string, date_string);

  Serial.println(time_string);
}
```

I can't test the code right now, but I hope this gives you a few ideas.

Comment: Alright sure. Will try editing the code tomorrow once i get back to school. Will update once everything is done. Thanks alot.